# Combining Rich Text Content Control Content in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I'm trying to create a form for a non-technical user in MS Word to capture some text content in MS Word.  This word doc consists of several rich text content controls where the user will type in or paste in some formatted data (bold, underlined, links, ...).

Once they get all the content entered into these various content controls I'm trying to make it easy for them to combine them together to paste in a consistent order into some podcast show notes which is in an HTML form.

So basically, I want to take three rich text content controls that have formatted data in them, combine them together into one formatted piece of content, and then copy it to the clipboard so they can then go to this web form, paste it in, and do some minor cleanup.  The problem is that whenever I try to combine the RTF content it loses the formatting.

The only way I seem to be able to keep the formatting is if I copy the range object and then paste it.  However, this doesn't paste just the formatted text.  It pastes the whole rich text content control.

I've tried creating a blank RTF field at the bottom of the Word doc to combine everything in but I just can't figure it out.  I wouldn't think this would be rocket science.

Being none of the code I've tried works and keeps the formatting I"m not sure if posting it here will do any good.  Here's how I'm getting the value of the text object:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtShowNotes").Item(1).Range.Text
```

tried this:

```
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtShowNotes").Item(1).Range.Copy
ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtCombinedContentSection").Item(1).Range.Paste
```

but this copies the whole RTF and not just the text.

Comment: Since your end goal is HTML, your process would be much simpler if you abandon Word and just use HTML.What kind of content are they pasting in? If it's web-sourced, they're already have an HTML input.

Comment: Problem is this word doc gets passed around and completed by several people and it needs to get stored for posterity so trying to fit into their normal process.  They also have no funding to do anything fancier.

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set Rng = .SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtCombinedContentSection").Item(1).Range
  Rng.FormattedText = _
    .SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtShowNotes").Item(1).Range.FormattedText
  Rng.InsertAfter vbCr & vbCr
  Rng.Characters.Last.FormattedText = _
    .SelectContentControlsByTitle("txtShowNotes").Item(2).Range.FormattedText
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That works!  Thank you so much for your expertise and taking time out of your day to assist!  If you're ever in Minneapolis beers on me!